# Could bcrypts AES-256 GCM encryption corrupt ZIP files?

Tags: python, c, corruption, aes-gcm

I'm trying to encrypt a ZIP file using AES-256 GCM in C and decrypting it in Python. Here is the C code I'm using:

```c
NTSTATUS generateRandomBytes(BYTE *buffer, ULONG length)
{
    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hProvider;
    NTSTATUS status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&hProvider, BCRYPT_RNG_ALGORITHM, NULL, 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        return status;
    }

    status = BCryptGenRandom(hProvider, buffer, length, 0);
    BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hProvider, 0);
    return status;
}

NTSTATUS encrypt_AES_GCM(const BYTE *plainData, ULONG plainDataLength,
                         const BYTE *iv, ULONG ivLength,
                         const BYTE *key, ULONG keyLength,
                         BYTE *encryptedData, ULONG encryptedDataLength,
                         BYTE *authTag, ULONG authTagLength)
{
    NTSTATUS status = 0;
    DWORD bytesDone = 0;
    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE algHandle = 0;
    status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&algHandle, BCRYPT_AES_ALGORITHM, NULL, 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        return status;
    }

    status = BCryptSetProperty(algHandle, BCRYPT_CHAINING_MODE, (PBYTE)BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_GCM, sizeof(BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_GCM), 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(algHandle, 0);
        return status;
    }

    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE keyHandle = 0;
    status = BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey(algHandle, &keyHandle, NULL, 0, (PUCHAR)key, keyLength, 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(algHandle, 0);
        return status;
    }

    BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO authInfo;
    BCRYPT_INIT_AUTH_MODE_INFO(authInfo);
    authInfo.pbNonce = (PUCHAR)iv;
    authInfo.cbNonce = ivLength;
    authInfo.pbTag = authTag;
    authInfo.cbTag = authTagLength;

    status = BCryptEncrypt(keyHandle, (PUCHAR)plainData, plainDataLength, &authInfo, NULL, 0, encryptedData, encryptedDataLength, &bytesDone, 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        BCryptDestroyKey(keyHandle);
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(algHandle, 0);
        return status;
    }

    BCryptDestroyKey(keyHandle);
    BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(algHandle, 0);

    return status;
}

int GCM_Encrypt_File(char *FileToEncrypt, char *keys, char *OutputFile)
{
    int fd;
    long file_size;
    char *input;
    _sopen_s(&fd, FileToEncrypt, _O_RDONLY, _SH_DENYRW, _S_IREAD);
    file_size = _filelength(fd);
    input = (char *)malloc(file_size);
    size_t bytes_read = fread(input, 1, file_size, _fdopen(fd, "rb"));
    BYTE key[32];
    BYTE iv[12];
    BYTE KeyTagIV[60];
    BYTE *encrypted;
    ULONG encryptedSize = file_size;
    ULONG authTagLength = 16;
    BYTE authTag[16];

    // Generate key and iv
    generateRandomBytes(key, sizeof(key));
    generateRandomBytes(iv, sizeof(iv));
    // Concatenate key and IV
    memcpy(KeyTagIV, key, sizeof(key));
    memcpy(KeyTagIV + sizeof(key), iv, sizeof(iv));
    // Print the info

    encrypted = (BYTE *)malloc(encryptedSize);

    // Encrypt
    encrypt_AES_GCM((BYTE *)input, file_size, iv, 12, key, 32, encrypted, encryptedSize, authTag, authTagLength);
    
    // Print data
    printf("KEY:\n");
    for (ULONG i = 0; i < sizeof(key); i++)
    {
        printf("%02X", key[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("IV:\n");
    for (ULONG i = 0; i < sizeof(iv); i++)
    {
        printf("%02X", iv[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Authentication tag:\n");
    for (ULONG i = 0; i < authTagLength; i++)
    {
        printf("%02X", authTag[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Add authentication tag to the KeyTagIV variable 
    memcpy(KeyTagIV + 44, authTag, authTagLength);
    memcpy(keys, KeyTagIV, 60);
    printf("FULL:\n");
    for (ULONG i = 0; i < 60; i++)
    {
        printf("%02X", KeyTagIV[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    FILE *encryptedFile = fopen(OutputFile, "wb");
    fwrite(encrypted, sizeof(char), file_size, encryptedFile);
    free(encrypted);
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
        // GCM Encrypt the File.
        char key_data[60];
        char path[] = "test.txt";
        char path1[] = "test.enc";
        GCM_Encrypt_File(path, key_data, path1);
        printf("Decryption Data:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
            printf("%02X ", key_data[i]);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

and I'm trying to decrypt the data with this Python code:

```py
import rsa
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
import os
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Decryption data in HEX KEY; IV; TAG
    KEYS = """540AA548ADBBF19820FEC1DDF9BC19B6230A746C0CF0EA87E083FDF314867DA525F299D2B9FEBC26A864A9F149D3A60B05E03CA9C3328E5AB10228DB"""
    encrypted_keys = bytearray.fromhex(KEYS)

    ENC_PATH = "test.enc"
    keys_data = encrypted_keys

    key = keys_data[:32]
    iv = keys_data[32:44]
    authTag = keys_data[44:60]
    ciphertext = open(ENC_PATH, mode="rb").read()
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=iv)
    plaintext = cipher.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, authTag)
    with open('decrypted_test.txt', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(plaintext)
    print("Done.")

#decrypt_rsa(input_filename, output_filename)
```

**This code seems to work, when for example encrypting a .txt file with just "Hello, world!". So it's able to decrypt it correctly.**

The problem is that when I try and encrypt a .zip file like this:
[image]

The decrypted output data looks like this:

[image]

**The .txt file is gone, and the test2.zip says "Corrupted" when trying to open. The test1.zip still opens correctly.**

*Could the algorithm be corrupting it? Or is there something wrong in my code?*

Comment: Seeing as how AES has been around for decades, analyzed and re-analyzed by scores of brilliant mathematical minds, and has copious amounts of real life field experience on a wide range of highly visible applications, I think it's safe to assume the algorithm is airtight. Could there be a bug in bcrypt's implementation? Possibly, but unlikely for the same reasons. The far-and-away most likely explanation for the problem you're seeing is bug(s) in your code.

Comment: Yes, I came to the same conclusion. But I can't see anything notably wrong in my code, since the C code is able to correctly encrypt "Hello, world!" .txt file and Python is able to decrypt that file...

Comment: Hopefully someone who knows about this stuff (not me) will come along, but some general thoughts to help with debugging: Use the same, hardcoded key rather than generating a new one each time. Compare your encryption/decryption parts with readily available (and known working) implementations online, this will at least narrow down which part (or both) are problematic.

Comment: `ULONG encryptedSize = file_size;` looks fishy to me. Looks like you're assuming the encrypted file length will be the same as the plaintext length, which I don't think you can count on at all. I know AES is a block cipher that will fill in padding if the PT data doesn't perfectly match. Maybe bcrypt hides those kind of implementation details from you, but perhaps double check the documentation for `BCryptEncrypt`.

Comment: @yano I think the key implementation works, since I've tried this dozens of times, with just copying the key from the C output to the Python script, and it succeeds in decryption every time. But I myself the problem lays somewhere in the file writing and reading.

Comment: I've read many times online that with PCKS1 padding, the plaintext is the same size as the ciphertext. With a quick Google search I got this ["GCM is a counter mode, so the ciphertext is the same length as plaintext, because it's a stream cipher."](https://www.reddit.com/r/cryptography/comments/11wvpdu/comment/jd05cvi/). I will try and dig more into binary encrypting with bcrypt's GCM implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [open `fd` in binary mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sopen-s-wsopen-s?view=msvc-170).

```
_sopen_s(&fd, FileToEncrypt, _O_RDONLY, _SH_DENYRW, _S_IREAD);
```

should be

```
_sopen_s(&fd, FileToEncrypt, _O_RDONLY | _O_BINARY, _SH_DENYRW, _S_IREAD);
```